# allauth urls are not accessible - 404 error

Tags: django, url, django-2.2

Can someone please help to solve my issue. Thanks in advance

when i try to access 'accounts/' in django,then causing 404 error.
I'm using allauth.

**URL Trying to access :** http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/

**URL's below are showing errors:**
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/
Using the URLconf defined in videoservice.urls, Django tried
these URL patterns, in this order:

```
    admin/
    accounts/ ^ ^signup/$ [name='account_signup']
    accounts/ ^ ^login/$ [name='account_login']
    accounts/ ^ ^logout/$ [name='account_logout']
    accounts/ ^ ^password/change/$ [name='account_change_password']
    accounts/ ^ ^password/set/$ [name='account_set_password']
    accounts/ ^ ^inactive/$ [name='account_inactive']
    accounts/ ^ ^email/$ [name='account_email']
    accounts/ ^ ^confirm-email/$ 
    [name='account_email_verification_sent']
    accounts/ ^ ^confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$ 
    [name='account_confirm_email']
    accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/$ [name='account_reset_password']
    accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/done/$ 
    [name='account_reset_password_done']
    accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(? 
    P<key>.+)/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key']
    accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/key/done/$ 
    [name='account_reset_password_from_key_done']
    accounts/ ^social/
    ^static/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
```

The current path, accounts/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: What about http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/ accessibility?

Comment: Hi @AshishNautiyal, it's giving the following error. when i try as you suggested. [02/Jun/2021 10:50:53] "GET /accounts/signup HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[02/Jun/2021 10:50:54] "GET /accounts/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Not Found: /accounts/profile/

Comment: Yes its redirecting to profile by default. The problem is if you look closely to patterns tried by django are :

/accounts/signup/ 
/accounts/ login/
/accounts/ logout/      etc...

and you are trying to access /accounts/ only(with no suffix) so its not matching to any of the patterns in urls.py of allauth, For better understanding just go through urlpatterns defined in urls.py of allauth and try to access them accordingly.

Comment: Hi @AshishNautiyal, tried the url -->http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup, still the same error. Please see the attached.

Comment: you ddin't got my point for signup to work you need to add  a Pattern in urls.py like : path('accounts/profile/',
         TemplateView.as_view(template_name='profile.html')), Explicitly. Go through allauth link to github https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/example/example/urls.py . Try other urls like 127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/ etc.

Comment: I've fixed it. Nothing to do with it. I just ran the syncdb, and it works. Also, when you are working with allauth, i really don't think that we need to add url's manually as you described above. as all the allauth url's comes as a set. Thanks @AshishNautiyal

Comment: python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

Answer (score 2):

A warning for those searching this problem.

I recently had the same error when trying to reach http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/. The reason was that I was logged in as the admin. After I signed out from the admin page, the problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by running the command "**python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb**".